# Android packet analyze

Tags: java, android, traffic, nmap

I am new here, so please excuse my unfamiliarity with the Q&A conventions, here.

I am trying to write an Android app which will capture `NMAP` scan, for example. I am looking to find a way to analyze traffic without rooting my android device. My goal is to see if someone is port scanning, and to report the data in this format: `-- Protocol -- Source IP -- Port -- TIME--`.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Hi, Peter, and welcome to StackOverflow! Just a quick tip for you, moving forward: whenever you ask a question, be sure to add any and all relevant work (code, research, etc.) that you have already done, on your own. This shows us that you have put in the time to try to find the answer yourself before bringing the question to the group. You will find that users on StackOverflow will be much more likely to put in the time to help you if you show them that you have already put in the time to help yourself. Good luck, and happy coding! :)

Comment: Well, I actually started with tcpdump and I was trying to read the pcap file, but my teacher (this is an assignment) told me that my app should be able to capture high-frequency packets arriving on consecutive ports without using tcpdump. Also, he told me that I don't need to read whats in the packet, I only need to know whether there is a storm of packets on consecutive ports. The problem is I really don't know how to do it, and that is why I asked this question here. I just need few tips in order to find a starting point.